# Colour gradient on a map in R (using image)

Tags: r, maps

I am trying to create a map just to get a concept across, not actually display real data.  So far I have the following code:

```
library(maps)
image(x=-100:10, y = -10:80, z = outer(-360:-250, -10:80), xlab = "lon", ylab = "lat")
map("world", col="gray", fill=TRUE, add=TRUE)
box()
```

Which in part I pulled together from some other forum posts. It creates this.

[image]

The bit I am struggling with is I want the gradational red-yellow-white colours to run N to S (it is just to demonstrate the direction of a trend).  They are nearly there, but I cant seem to get the configuration of 'z' correct and I have a feeling I am doing a bad bodge and there is a proper solution.  For info, I also want to create the same map with the gradient running E to W, ideally in a different colour palette.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to eliminate the "curl" (i.e. how the red is darker in the top left than the top right?

Comment: Yes that would be another way of putting it, so the colour is equal horizontally but changes vertically.

Comment: I posted an answer.  Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for making the color more even.

```
x <- -100:10
y <- -10:80
r <- outer(x, y^3, "+")
image(x, y, z = r, col  = rev(heat.colors(30)), xlab = "lon", ylab = "lat")
map("world", col = "grey", fill = TRUE, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

And to change the direction of the color, adjust `r`,

```
x <- -100:10
y <- -10:80
r <- outer(x^3, y, "+")
image(x, y, z = r, col  = heat.colors(30), xlab = "lon", ylab = "lat")
map("world", col = "grey", fill = TRUE, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: That is great.  Thank you ever so much.  I ended up modifying a bit and using:
    'mypalette<-brewer.pal(7,"Blues")
image(1:7,1,as.matrix(1:7),col=mypalette,xlab="Blues (sequential)",
      ylab="",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",bty="n")

x <- -100:10
y <- -10:80
r <- outer(x, y*450, "-")
image(x, y, z = r, col = mypalette, xlab = "lon", ylab = "lat")
map("world", col = "grey", fill = TRUE, add = TRUE)
box()'